# Is there a modern wine that is designed to resemble Noah's wine?

Tags: wine, history

After seeing this question once again on this site [(Is there a modern wine that is designed to resemble ancient Roman winemaking?)](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/5071/is-there-a-modern-wine-that-is-designed-to-resemble-ancient-roman-winemaking/5076#5076) sometime back and I became interested in knowing if there is a modern wine that is designed to resemble [Noah's wine](https://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/biblical-sites-places/biblical-archaeology-places/did-this-winery-get-noah-drunk/) from the Turkish region of Mt. Ararat after the biblical deluge? I am not interested if one believes in the story of Noah's Ark or not. Nor am I interested in any possible historical timeline for the great regional flood which spared Noah and his family.

> Noah's wine is a colloquial allusion meaning alcoholic beverages. The advent of this type of beverage and the discovery of fermentation are traditionally attributed, by explication from biblical sources, to Noah. The phrase has been used in both fictional and nonfictional literature.
>
> **"Noah's wine"** refers to alcoholic beverages. In the Bible, the few chapters that come between the creation of Adam and the birth of Noah contain no mention of alcoholic drinks. After the account of the great flood, the biblical Noah is said to have cultivated a vineyard, made wine, and become intoxicated. Thus, the discovery of fermentation is traditionally attributed to Noah because this is the first time alcohol appears in the Bible. Noah's wine has been described as a "pleasant relief for man from the toilsome work of the crop".
>
> From a biblical view, fermented beverages presumably spread throughout the world after Noah's supposed discovery, as alcoholic beverages are historically widespread. - [Noah's wine (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noah%27s_wine)

**Is there a modern wine, commercially available today, that is intended to resemble the ancient Noah's wine as closely as possible from any of his many possible [timelines](https://answersingenesis.org/bible-timeline/timeline-for-the-flood/) (more or less)?**

[Noah’s Original Identity: The First Winemaker](https://thetorah.com/noahs-original-identity-the-first-winemaker/)

[image: A depiction from the Holkham Bible c. 1320 AD showing Noah and his sons making wine]

A depiction from the [Holkham Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holkham_Bible) c. 1320 AD showing Noah and his sons making wine

Comment: "Thus, the discovery of fermentation is traditionally attributed to Noah because this is the first time alcohol appears in the Bible" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_alcoholic_drinks. Noah's wine, I do not think i would drink that koolaid if it was available. **Mmmm, angry and vengeful god you are, seduced you the dark-side has !**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Karasì** is not designed to resemble that of Noah's wine, but it may have some small characteristics of the grapes Noah used.

> **Karasì**, is a tribute to the 6100 year wine tradition of Armenia. Aged in traditional amphorae, hence its name, ‘from amphorae’ in Armenia, this wine embraces the living heritage of a country while at the same time it delves back into a long forgotten chapter in the ancient history of wine.
>
> **Grape Variety**
>
> The King of Armenia’s grapes and possibly one of the oldest grape varieties in the world Areni has been present in Armenia for millennia. Never grafted and on its own roots, it is 100% indigenous to this land with a unique DNA proﬁle that does not match any other. Elegant and fresh, thick skinned and extremely resistant to disease, through the ages Areni has adapted perfectly to the high altitudes and extreme temperatures variations of Vayots Dzor, its natural habitat.
>
> With Karasì we have the pleasure of tasting both place and the exotic personality of an ancient grape most have never heard of! - [Karasì](https://www.zorahwines.com/karasi/)
>
> **The Cradle of Vine and Wine**
>
> One of the world’s oldest civilizations, steeped in a history and tradition that dates back millennia, Armenia’s territory lies in the southern Trans Caucasus in the highlands surrounding Biblical Mount Ararat. The Cradle of Vine and Wine, the vine has forever been present in the valleys of Armenia with the wild Vitis vinifera silvestris, ancestor of the cultivated vinifera vine species, already established in its highlands over a million years ago.
>
> It is also of course in Armenia, at the foothills of Biblical Mount Ararat, where legend has Noah, the world’s first vigneron, plant his vineyards and later became famously drunk on his own wine! - [Armenia: The land of the beginning](https://www.zorahwines.com/armenia/)
>
> **Championing Native Varieties**
>
> Working uniquely with ancient native varieties the vines are planted on their own roots directly into rocky, limestone soils which have never seen Phylloxera and while ZORAH’S heirloom vineyards tell a story of times gone by, the younger vines, the cuttings of which come from ancient abandoned vineyards of a XIIIth Century monastery, show us vistas into a possible future. - [Zorah Wines](https://www.zorahwines.com/vineyards/)

Comment: I doubt it has never been grafted. Most of the worlds wine grapes were wiped out in the phylloxera epidemic. Read the third paragraph. http://www.fao.org/europe/news/detail-news/en/c/1025493/

Answer (score 4):

These guys aren't claiming that it's Noah's wine, but they are saying they are using the same methods that they used 8000 years ago to make wine and you can buy it in the Republic of Georgia. [Is Georgia's Ancient Wine Making Method Making a Comeback?](https://medium.com/@foodmatters/is-georgias-ancient-wine-making-method-making-a-comeback-fd54db9946dc) You can buy it around the world supposedly.

*"Kvevri wines from Georgia can be found in a few stores and restaurants in New York City, San Francisco and Washington DC. Noel Brockett, who distributes both conventional and kvevri wine from Georgia in Washington DC for the Georgia Wine House, says it may take time to reach the general public but, “the Sommelier community is definitely becoming much more interested in the kvevri wines as the general market turns toward authenticity.”*

Other than trying something out for historical purposes, the wine probably didn't taste all that great. They probably drank it young since they didn't have bottles and it was likely very cloudy and low alcohol. Probably not red since that would require fermenting on the skins in a controlled manner. Probably like a cloudy rose' or a orangeish white. We'll never know what grapes were used by Noah.